# Improve and optimize fluidity ( no lag ) of an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, optimization

I have a ( little ) big problem with my app which is not fluid at all when I build it on my iPhone 4 ( it's perfectly fluid on iPhone 5 )..
I made all my images lighter but nothing changes. There are no 3D or 2D animations, only "push" transitions between my views. I'm a beginner in iOS development and I think ( maybe i'm false ) that there are optimizations tips to do in the code to make the fluidity more efficient. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There is no way to help since you have not provided any useful information. But in general, when having performance issues, use Instruments and see where the actual performance issues are in the app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Actually, since I don't know my problem, I don't know what information could be useful for you ?

Comment: Use Instruments - Time Profiler

Comment: remove as much transparencies in you views as possible. In the iOS Simulator you can use | Debug -> Color Blended Layers | to see if you have many blened views.

Comment: When I active Color Blended Layers in the iOS simulator i get this :
http://imageshack.us/a/img17/1990/capturedcran20130531175.png
I don't know how to interprete this, i guess red boxes are not good haha. Is there a way to solve it ? Can it be the reason of the lack of fluidity ? THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have graphic rendering or animations maybe you have some bottlenecks in the data loading process. So actually the UI components have to wait for the data that they display and thus their drawing is delayed.
For example a simple UITableView can lag significantly if it displays cells that have images in it and the images come from a network source and they are loaded synchronously. This piece of code can provide a huge delay on bad networks

```
someTableViewCell.imageView.image = [self getImageFromSomeInternetServer];
```

This is just a simple example but it's a good starting point to look for bottlenecks because you have not provided any code or info what exactly is wrong with your app.

Also as this guy commented your question use Instruments. One of the presets measures the execution time of your code and calculates the percentage. Use that and you can see which pieces of code are the most time consuming and need optimization.

Comment: Ok thank you, 
I'm really sorry to not being detailed in the explanation of my problem. All i can say easily about it, is that the transition between views is not fluid even if there is no access to a network source to load datas.. It's getting very annoying for me. All that is loaded ( images mostly ) is from a local repository.

I'll try to use Instruments.